# Dropdown not showing elements Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a issue with the dropdown element of bootstrap 3. It's not showing the elements.
The reason is because I'm having a conflict with the css off "wrapper"

```
#wrapper    { width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; overflow:hidden; }
```

You will probably said remove it and it works. But I can't do that. I'm trying to do a parallex effect. This [one](http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/116_parallax/tutorial-source-files/tut-index.html) being more specific.

And having that style is part of doing the parallex effect. I though of changing the top size, but it wouldn't work if the dropdown gets more elements.

I have a [demo](http://jsbin.com/nonila/2/edit?html,css) showing the issue.

Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your "divide-nav" class this styles:

```
.divide-nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: it works, I'm not a CSS,expert could you explain why it works?

Comment: The thing is - your #wrapper was above your dropdown, and in fact you were clicking on #wrapper, not dropdown. "z-index" - put dropdown above #wrapper. It's like layouts in Photoshop, if you now what i mean. You can read about z-index here http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp